# Is it possible to make vb write code itself?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

As I'm was writing this giant class, I was thinking that it is basic enough to be easily scriptable, let me give an example

```
Public Class BigClass
    Private _Att1 as Single
    Public Property Att1 as Single
    Get 
        return _Att1
    End Get
    Set(value as Single)
        Dim v = value - _Att1
        _Att1 = value
        Dependent1 += v * 0.25
        Dependent2 += v * 3
    End Set

    Public Property Dependent1 as single
    Public Property Dependent2 as single
End Class
```

And this over and over, there is over a 100 properties to write and most of them receive a simple trickledown effect from other properties.

This would go much faster and would be more maintainable if I could just write it in pseudo code like this:

```
    Att1;
    Dependent1; Att1, 0.25;
    Dependent2; Att1, 3;
```

In this imaginary language, each line defines a property. After the first semicolon each following statement ending in a semicolon defines a dependency on some other attribute and the multiplier.

My question is, is it possible to have that custom script language in a file in the project and have visual studio(2013) parse it into a .vb file/code in realtime? Sorta like the visual designer is actually writing a .vb file?

One way I can see it working is that I make a little "compiler" executable that visual studio runs every time I stop editing the source file.

Comment: Take a look at [T4 Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

Comment: that is exactly it! thanks.